# Actionscript 3.0 Button not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

Here is the deal, this animation, when added by a click on

```
what_mc
```

works fine!

But if I add the

```
whatanim_mc.case_mc
```

next to it, doesn't work anymore. I get no errors. What do I do?

```
what_mc.whatanim_mc.case_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,WhatIsCase);

function WhatIsCase(evt:Event):void
{

    if(what_mc.currentFrame > targetFrame) stage.addEventListener
(Event.ENTER_FRAME,GoWhatIsCase);
}

function GoWhatIsCase(evt:Event):void {
    intelmini_mc.prevFrame();
    back_mc.prevFrame();
    what_mc.prevFrame();

    cross1_mc.play();


    if(what_mc.currentFrame <= targetFrame) stage.removeEventListener
(Event.ENTER_FRAME,GoWhatIsCase);
}
```

Appreciate the help :)
Thank you!

Comment: what is targetFrame here?

Comment: var targetFrame = 1;

Every animation has 20 frames. When a few are activated, others rollback.

Comment: you don't mean an instance name of **whatanim_mc.case_mc** with the dot, do you?